# Custom field in Drupal 7 with multiple file fields

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

I'm making a custom "video" field that is supposed to accept several files (for different video formats) and a caption. So far the schema is fine, but I can't get it to upload and store the actual files.

My code in `hook_field_widget_form` looks like this (only pasting relevant bits):

```
$element['mp4'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => 'MP4 file',
  '#delta' => $delta,
);
$element['ogg'] = ... /* similar to the mp4 one */
$element['caption'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Caption',
  '#delta' => $delta,
);
```

Also, in my `.install` file:

```
function customvideofield_field_schema($field) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'mp4' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'ogg' => ... /* similar to mp4 */
      'caption' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

And the error I'm getting is when I try to store data. I get the form ok, and the database looks fine (the fields Drupal generates at least), but when it tries to do an INSERT, it fails because the value it tries to get into those integer fields is an empty string.

From what I understand, they have to be integers, right? (`fid`s?) But I'm guessing the files are not being uploaded, even though I do get the right interface for uploading files.

Drupal shows you the INSERT query it tries to do, which is too long to post here, but I can see there that the value for the `caption` field (which is just a text field), is fine in the query, so it's only a problem with the file fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`managed_file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) field type instead, it handles uploading the file and registering it in the `managed_files` table for you. Then you would just add a submit function to your widget form and put the following code (from the FAPI page linked to above):

```
// Load the file via file.fid.
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['mp4']);

// Change status to permanent.
$file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

// Save.
file_save($file);

// Record that the module (in this example, user module) is using the file. 
file_usage_add($file, 'customvideofield', 'customvideofield', $file->fid);
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

The core file module handles the actual submission for this using [`hook_field_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7), my best guess is that this code would work:

```
function customvideofield_field_presave($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, &$items) {
  // Make sure that each file which will be saved with this object has a
  // permanent status, so that it will not be removed when temporary files are
  // cleaned up.
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $file = file_load($item['mp4']);
    if (!$file->status) {
      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
      file_save($file);
    }
  }
}
```

That assumes the file ID column for your field is the one called `mp4`.

Remember to clear Drupal's caches when you implement the new hook or it won't be registered.

Comment: this is really putting me in the right direction, thanks! Do you know where I should put this code though? Is it `hook_field_update_field()`?

Comment: So if you use `hook_field_presave` there's no need to register the file as being used using `file_usage_add`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried file uploading in my Drupal modules yet, but can you check does your form tag have the attribute enctype
="multipart/form-data"?

I would expect Drupal ought to include this automatically, but without it the file fields won't work, which seems to be what you're experiencing.

James